# I have a UITapGestureRecognizer added to an UIViewController's view that is in a UITableViewCell in a UITableView, why won't it fire?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

The title is pretty explanatory, but I have a UITableView that I am populating with custom UITableViewCells.

Inside of these custom UITableViewCells, I am adding custom UIViewControllers that display custom images.

To this UIViewController's UIView, I am adding a UITapGestureRecognizer as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                             action:@selector(handleTap:)];
recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
recognizer.delegate = self;
[self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

[recognizer release];
}

-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender{
NSLog(@"Handling tap on ArticleTileViewController");
}
```

When I run the app, the cells are populating the images great, but when I tap on the image(or the custom UIViewController), nothing happens! My NSLog won't fire. I have looked over the code for an hour now, and don't see where I am going wrong.

Does anybody see something I'm missing? Or have they run into this before?

Comment: I think it would be better to have a UIView or UIImageView subclass instead of using a UIViewController.  Unless your view is farily complicated, it is better to subclass UIView rather than UIViewController.  In your case, just displaying a custom image, it sounds tailor made for either a UIImageView subclass or possibly even just UIImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get a button on each cell, here is a post on how to do it. Take a look.
[iPhone SDK: Opening a cell with a dedicated button, not by cell tapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416174/iphone-sdk-opening-a-cell-with-a-dedicated-button-not-by-cell-tapping/3416366#3416366)

Comment: I suppose that would give me the same effect. I'll try it out. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

`UIImageView` objects have their `userInteractionEnabled` set to `NO` by default. This might be the case here as well. Add

```
self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

to the `viewDidLoad` method that you've presented in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
       UILongPressGestureRecognizer* gesture = [[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)] autorelease];
       gesture.delegate = self;
       [myWebView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
      return YES;
}
```