# Getting the data of a particular row with a button infront of it and passing that data to the clickButton function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I am currently in the cellForRow method where I have a button infront of each row.

```
CellForRow:
JSONDecoder *decoder=[[JSONDecoder alloc] initWithParseOptions:JKParseOptionNone];
NSMutableArray *json=[decoder objectWithData:myData]; {This has a list of items in the dictionary format}

NSDictionary *dict=[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
NSString *status=[dict valueForKey:@"status key in json"];

"dict" can be represented as:
{
   status key in json="approved";
   name="abc";
   type="resourceName";
},
{
   status key in json="rejected"; 
   name="xyz";
   type="bus";

},
{
   status key in json ="pending";
   name="pqr";
   type="resource";  
 }...and so on .
```

Printing status will give me the status of all the rows. 
approved
rejected
pending

But I only need the status of that particular row infront of which I am gonna click the button. This is because I need that status for each row separately to send it to the buttonPressed method when I click the button infront of that row. I don't want to do that in didSelectRow method.

How can I get the indexPath.row of a particular row(on clicking that row) so that I could write the method on click of the button corresponding to that particular row?

Comment: Is your issue resolved? Is there any problem?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add the button as subview for your cell, and pass indexpath.row as a button tag.Thats it.

I have given the sample

//Create ur cell then do the following

```
UIButton *objBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[objBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(100,5,50,50)];
[objBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(methodWhichGetsCallOnButtonClick:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
objBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell addSubview:objBtn];
```

Now in "methodWhichGetsCallOnButtonClick" method add your business logic.

**[Also take a look on this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416174/iphone-sdk-opening-a-cell-with-a-dedicated-button-not-by-cell-tapping/3416366#3416366)**

EDIT:

[Also See this link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Simple_iPhone_Table_View_Application)

Try this out, and revert me back if need any more help.

Comment: shikha have you tried this logic posted above, and also take a look on link which i have provided.

Comment: I am implementating the same procedure. But I'm not facing any problem here. I just want to get the data corresponding to a particular row in the cellForRow method. Look at my question again . If I print NSLog(@"%@",status) I am getting the status of all the rows. But I want the status of only a specific row

Comment: when I click on the first row(not the button) "approved" should be printed on the console. On click of 2nd row " rejected" should be printed on console...and so on ...there are many rows

Comment: Shikha, see d logic which we have here, will add a button to a cell as a subview. And we are setting its selector (method for on button click action), so if you select the cell then "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" method will get called, and if you click on button then its associated method will get called(here in our condition it's: methodWhichGetsCallOnButtonClick). so all the logic for button click will goes here. Just make me one thing clear that YOU WANT THAT STRING TO BE PRINTED ON **CELL CLICK** OR ON **BUTTON CLICK**

Comment: on cell click that's what I am trying to say.
and I want to implement that in cellForRow method...not didSelect method

Comment: This is very contradict, Your question is **(Getting the data of a particular row with a button infront of it and passing that data to the clickButton function)** and now you want it on **cell click** can you please clear out the things, so that this will help us to proceed in that way.

Comment: I think I'd better post another question to clear out the misunderstandings

Comment: Dont go on posting much questions,for the same issue, people on SO may downgrade it. This is **very very simple thing** that you wann do. I am posting another link, hope this will help you. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Simple_iPhone_Table_View_Application

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you want indexPath of cell on button clicked.You can get the cell of that button(in button action) as follows:

```
UIButton *theButton = sender;
CreatedCell *cell = (CreatedCell *)[[theButton superview] superview];
```

After getting cell, you can get indexPath of that cell as follows:

```
theIndexPath = [[m_TableView indexPathForCell:cell] retain];
```

Comment: I need the indexPath of the cell before I click on the button. That is why I need it in the cellForRow method

Comment: indexPath.row is not helping as it gives me statuses of all the rows.

Comment: You want to display status in each cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tag to UIButton.

In cellForRowAtIndexPath Method

You set tag to Button like this

btn.tag=indexpath.row;

In Button Action method you can retrive tag value using this line

Action method for Button
-(void)btnAction:(id)sender

{

UIButton *btn=(UIButton *) sender;

int tagValue=btn.tag;
NSDictionary *dict=[json objectAtIndex:tagValue];

// From this dictionory you cann acces the stauts key  value

}

I hope it works for you

Comment: I am using the same. But I need the data of the row irrespective of the button I click. Please forget the button. I just need the data of a particular row in the cellFowRow method.

Comment: What is the problem when using this type of code? You did not accessing array?

Comment: I am implementating the same procedure. But I'm not facing any problem here. I just want to get the data corresponding to a particular row in the cellForRow method. Look at my question again . If I print NSLog(@"%@",status) I am getting the status of all the rows. But I want the status of only a specific row

Comment: when I click on the first row(not the button) "approved" should be printed on the console. On click of 2nd row " rejected" should be printed on console...and so on ...there are many rows

Comment: Are you NSLog in BtnAction method or cellForRowAtIndex Method?